VS Code experiences brief unresponsiveness or crashes
When the server sends a large number of logs for a long time, vscode does not respond or crashes for a short time.  How can I modify the following code to solve this problem?
let reocrdEndData = ''
class TestGetLog {
    static createActiveDatalog(logger: LogOutputChannel, context:ExtensionContext): void {
        const connect = createConnection({host: '127.0.0.1', post: 20001}, () => {
            logger.show()
            const sendPorts = [20001,20003]
            if(connect.localPort && sendPorts.includes(connect.localPort)) {
                connect.destroy()
                TestGetLog.createActiveDatalog(logger,context)
            }
        })

        connect.on('data', (data) => {
            const logData = reocrdEndData + String(data)
            const lines =logData.split('\n')
            let rebuildData = ''

            if(logData.endsWith('\n')) {
                reocrdEndData = ''
                rebuildData = lines.slice(0, lines.length -1).join('\n')
            } else {
                reocrdEndData = lines[lines.length -1]
                rebuildData = lines.slice(0, lines.length -2).join('\n')
            }

            logger.info(rebuildData)
        })

        connect.on('close', () => {
            connect.destroy()
        })
    }
}

I'd like to modify the code to fix the crash or non-response problem.  Thanks

1st segment your logger, like debug, warning, info, error etc. 2nd create a logger file and store all logs in there, terminal will show error & important logs. This will resolved your issue
